# Get Jquery index of element based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing

I need to find the index of element with class "span":

```
<div>
<div>
    <div class="sd">
        <h2> H2 TEXT </h2>
        <span> SPAN </span>
        <span class="span"> SPAN </span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

So i did:

```
var q = $('div > div > div.sd').find('.span').index();
alert(q)
```

This alerts "2" but the class is the first and only so it should alert "1". 
Is this because Jquery looks for the tag and not the class? I googled a lot and searched on stack but all examples include a click event which I don't want.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/jL7dsv5y/

Comment: From the documentation: If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting. It's the first and only of what?

Comment: Indexes are zero-based, so if you think it's the first, shouldn't it alert `0`?

Comment: @Barmar Its the first and only of element with class "span". Are you saying it can't be done with Jquery index?

Comment: You can give an argument to `index`, and it will find its position within that collection.

Comment: @Barmar I had "1" in the back of my head because I was transforming it in :nth-child in my script but you are right, I meant "0"

Comment: @Barmar Yes I tried `$('div > div > div.sd').index('.span');` But it doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply `.index()` to a collection, and pass an element to it, it will return the position of that element within the collection. This will alert `0` because the `.span` element within the `div` is the first of all the `.span` elements in the document.

```js
var q = $(".span").index($('div > div > div.sd').find('.span'));
alert(q);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="sd">
      <h2> H2 TEXT </h2>
      <span> SPAN </span>
      <span class="span"> SPAN </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, and thank you for elaborating on it:) Im always struggling with index